# Wordpress : why my custom sub-category search filter don't work?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, filter, categories

I edit my **wordpress** page **searchform.php** in theme to add **filter by subcategories**.
And i add a add_filter('the_search_query','search_filter') in my function.php

But when run a search : result dont care about my dropdown...

**==> My question : How to make search (filter) works with my catégory filter ?**

Hi have this :

[image]

whis this code in **searchform.php** :

```
<?php
$options_type = array(
 'name'               => 'subcat_type',
 'hierarchical'       => 1,
 'parent'             => get_category_by_slug('action-type')->term_id,
 'show_option_none'   => ("Type d’action"),
 'selected'           => (isset($_GET['subcat_type']) ? $_GET['subcat_type'] : ''),
 'hide_empty'   => 0  ); 

.......

?>

<form method="get" id="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
    <input class="search-box vntd-boxed-content" name="s" id="s" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : '' ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Que recherchez vous ?','vntd_renown') ?>">        
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($options_type); ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($options_thematiques); ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($options_public); ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($options_territoire); ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="my_search" name="my_search" value="c_search" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Rechercher" />
</form>
```

whis this code in **functions.php** :

```
<?php
// Define search filter
function search_filter( $query ) {
    // only modify your custom search query.
    if ( $query->is_search &&  $_post['my_search'] == "c_search") {
        $args = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['subcat_public']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['subcat_territoire']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['subcat_thematiques']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['subcat_type']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $args);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'the_search_query','search_filter');
?>
```

Thanks.

Nico

Comment: Resolved : 
function recherche_oris($query) {

 
 if (isset($_GET['my_search'])){
  
 if (isset($_GET['subcat_type']) && $_GET['subcat_type'] >= 0){
        $query->set('category__and', $_GET['subcat_type']);
    }
 ....
 }
 
    return $query;
}
//hook filters to search
add_filter('pre_get_posts','recherche_oris');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved :

```
function recherche_oris($query) {


    /*if (!$query->is_search) { 
        return $query;
    } else {
        echo "<pre>";   print_r( $query ); echo "</pre>";   
        die();
    }*/

    if (isset($_GET['my_search'])){

    if (isset($_GET['subcat_type']) && $_GET['subcat_type'] >= 0){
        $query->set('category__and', $_GET['subcat_type']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['subcat_thematiques']) && $_GET['subcat_thematiques'] >= 0){
        $query->set('category__and', $_GET['subcat_thematiques']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['subcat_public']) && $_GET['subcat_public'] >= 0){
        $query->set('category__and', $_GET['subcat_public']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['subcat_territoire']) && $_GET['subcat_territoire'] >= 0){
        $query->set('category__and', $_GET['subcat_territoire']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['tags'])){
        $query->set('tag__and', $_GET['tags']);
    }
    }

    return $query;
}
//hook filters to search
add_filter('pre_get_posts','recherche_oris');
```